# Split TextField Data to HH : mm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, split, nsdatecomponents

In my application I take user input about alert time as hour and minute. My input from user is from

```
@IBOutlet weak var morningHour: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eveningHour: UITextField!
```

and I implement hour : minute to my location as

```
var dateComponentsForMorning = DateComponents()
dateComponentsForMorning.hour = 08
dateComponentsForMorning.minute = 00
let triggerForMorning = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponentsForMorning, repeats: true)
```

My question is:
How can I split my input as HH:mm and implement to my code in swift ?

Comment: For such a case, I would *highly* recommend to use a UIDatePicker instead of two text fields with `.time` mode; It naturally work with Dates instead of Strings, which sounds more logical to your case.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Is the user typing a value in the form of HH:mm and you want to know how to split that string into an hour value and a minute value?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I think you understand it very clear. I'll try Ahmad's method.

Comment: @AhmadF I already have two picker on the page but I think I'll do with your way.